# The requested URL not found when laravel Installation on local server

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I am just add the laravel project inside of the /var/www/html folder. When I run the application in browswer using url
http://localhost/voting_lession/public/ It works fine, but it's any routes does not work, error is like this.
[image]

Comment: You should really be setting up a virtualhost (guessing you're using Apache) and point it to the public folder

Comment: yes ! i tried virtualhost  too and still same problem as above !

Comment: would you suggest me to make configure virtual host, when project folder is outside of the /var/www/html folder .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of
http://localhost/voting_lession/public/
Try index.php after your url it might be the issue 
http://localhost/voting_lession/public/index.php

Comment: would you suggest me to make configure virtual host, when project folder is outside of the /var/www/html folder .

Comment: @MadhuSudhanSubedi But why you want to keep project outside php server directory.

Comment: Because I want to manage different category of  projects in different folder, for e.g. test related projects in one directory, office projects  in another directory. I do not want add all the projects inside of server directory. Again I want to projects accessible using domain name that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You may activate the rewrite mode of apache it Will work.

Comment: I enabled the rewrite mode of apache, and I am giving the 755 permission for the /var/www/html folder But does not work again.

Comment: Try this 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: would you suggest me to make configure virtual host, when project folder is outside of the /var/www/html folder .

Answer (score 0):

Do check the path to your file for correctness in spelling; if your localhost is up as you said and Laravel properly installed, that is likely to be the problem.

Comment: Now problem solved !
would you suggest me to make configure virtual host, when project folder is outside of the /var/www/html folder .

Comment: Run the following Artisan Command: **php artisan serve --port=8080**, where *8080* corresponds to the port number you would like to avail your project on. Check [Running PHP's Built-in Web Server](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/282/running-phps-built-in-web-server) for more details.

Comment: The above should be easier and get you started faster. For a *virtual host* approach, check this [tuts](https://delanomaloney.com/2013/07/10/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-xampp/).